# SetWindowsHookEx, CBTProc and g++3.4.5 (mingw)

Tags: windows, dll, g++, hook

I'm currently working on an application that needs to add a menu
to each application's system menu. I can accomplish that for the existing
windows with the `EnumWindows` function.
For the new windows (applications starting up after mine)
I'm trying to do this with windows hooks. More specifically with `CBTProc`.
This is where I'm stuck. 
I've stripped about everything possible in the app, 
but I've got the impression the procedure in my dll just doesn't
get called at all.

Here's the code for the dll:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <fstream>
using std::ofstream;

#include <windows.h>

// ---------------------------------------------------
extern "C"
{
  void log(const string & msg)
  {
    ofstream out("out.log", std::ios_base::app);
    out << msg;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  }
  // ---------------------------------------------------  
  LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
    log("CBTProc");
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  }
  // ---------------------------------------------------  
}
```

I compile this with g++ 3.4.5 on a windows xp sp3 32bit machine:

```
g++ -shared -otest.dll test_dll.cpp
```

And here's the code for the application

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <windows.h>

typedef void (*func)();

void run()
{
  cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
  cin.get();
}

void * loadProc(HMODULE mod, const char * procname)
{
  void * retval = (void *)GetProcAddress(mod, procname);
  if (retval == NULL)
    cerr << "GetProcAddress(" << procname << ") failed" << endl;
  return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
  if (dll == NULL)
    {
      cerr << "LoadLibrary failed" << endl;
      return 1;
    }

  HOOKPROC proc = (HOOKPROC)loadProc(dll, "CBTProc@12");
  if (!proc)
    return 1;

  HHOOK callwnd = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, proc, dll, 0);
  if (callwnd == NULL)
    {
      cerr << "SetWindowsHookEx failed for CBTProc" << endl;
      return 1;
    }

  run();
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(callwnd);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile this with the same setup:

```
g++ -otest.exe test.cpp
```

When I run, I get no errors, but when I start up new applications I get nothing
in my logfile.

Any ideas?

gr,
ldx

**Edit:** spelling errors

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to check the following:

- ensure that your DLL has an export
  (can be checked with dumpbin tool). I
  don't know about g++, but in MSVC it
  is necessary to either use
  __declspec(dllexport) or explicitly state  exports in DEF file.
- ensure that your host application
  uses the    correct name of the
  exported function    (the same as
  "dumpbin /EXPORTS    test.dll"
  displays)
- keep in mind that    you are are    using relative file name    out.log -    when DLL gets loaded to    other    processes it would write      relatively to the host process' current directory. For    testing      purposes it would be better to use      OutputDebugString API and inspect      results with DbgView tool.

Chances are that your solution works already.

PS: it's not generally a good idea to use STL in an injected DLL. Make sure you are aware of the risks.